# How can I know where the package is located in texlive?

Tags: packages

I was trying to install the `mhchem` package on my computer (Ubuntu Budgie 22.04), and I didn't find the command on the internet, so I tried these:

```
sudo apt install texlive-mhchem
sudo apt install texlive-science-mhchem
```

The terminal said that it couldn't find the packages. In the end, I fixed the problem by just running this command

```
sudo apt install texlive-science
```

and installing every package in `texlive-science`. So, is there a document where all package paths are written? How could I know what commands to use when trying to install other packages next time?

I think I found something about the `/usr/ias/texlive` directory, but I don't have it on my PC.

Comment: `texlive-science` is what you want, various sites let you search apt eg https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-science/filelist  note ubuntu/debian packages texlive in largish "collections" to fit apt better,unlike texlive from tug you can not get individual latex packages

Answer (score 2):

`texlive-science` is what you want, various sites let you search apt eg https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-science/filelist

Note ubuntu/debian packages texlive in largish "collections" to fit apt better, unlike texlive from tug you can not get individual latex packages

eg looking for all apt packages that have `tabularray` I used

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=tabularray

so would need `texlive-latex-extra` to install via apt (if I had an apt-mangaged texlive)